# In ASP .Net, under what conditions (if any) does AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit fire?

Tags: asp.net, .net, appdomain

I have a class used ASP .Net and non-web applications that needs end-of-application finalization (it consumes a .Net Framework class that requires a cleanup call at app end).  When I run the following test code under IIS in ASP.Net, the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit never fires, even during an IIS reset... even though Application_End fires.

(NOTE: the test code-behind page does reference the class in a way that causes the static constructor to run)

```
public class A
{
    static A()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += A_Dtor;
    }

    public static string Text { get { return "Content"; } }
    public string B() { return "B"; }

    static void A_Dtor(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"c:\everyone\A_Dtor.txt"));
        sw.Write("test");
        sw.Close();

        Debug.WriteLine("Firing A_Dtor");
    }
}
```

Are there any conditions under which AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit fires for an ASP.Net application?

Comment: Doesn't fire for me when I stop debugging or when I right click IIS express and choose stop.  Session_End gets called for every session, but neither Process_Exit does not get called.  Although, CurrentDomain_DomainUnload does get called.